# Javascript accessing methods with brackets?

Tags: javascript

I saw this in some code:

`var _0xdf50x7 = document['createElement']('form');`

How does this work? Does this mean that an object's methods can be accessed like the elements of an array?

Comment: That form is usually used when the method name is in a variable: `var m = some_condition ? 'm1' : 'm2';o[m]();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the `createElement()` method is a [member](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) of the `document` object, it can be accessed using either [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Dot_notation):

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
```

Or [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation):

```
var form = document["createElement"]("form");
```

This can be useful if the name of the method to call is stored in a variable:

```
var methodName = "createElement";
var form = document[methodName]("form");
```

It can also be used if the actual method to call depends on external conditions. Here is a (contrived) example:

```
function createNode(str, isTextNode)
{
    return document[isTextNode ? "createTextNode" : "createElement"](str);
}
```

Comment: @user, sometimes they're useful if you have to compute the method to call and want to spare an `if` statement (or if the method name is stored in a variable, as others rightfully point out).

Comment: The bracket syntax doesn't help much if you're going to use a string literal in the brackets as in the example given, but it is useful if the function name is in a variable or if you want to apply some condition to choose which function, e.g., `document[someFunction]();` or `document[someCondition ? "someFunction" : "someOtherFunction"]();`

Comment: Also, where can I learn more about the if statement notation with the question mark?

Comment: The *ternary conditional operator*? You can learn more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Conditional_Operator).