# Strange use of square braces to call functions

Tags: javascript

How does calling functions with square braces work?

```
100['toString']//function toString() { [native code] }
100['toString']['length']//1
```

What exactly is happening here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript accessing methods with brackets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062258/javascript-accessing-methods-with-brackets)

Comment: Short answer: **everything in JavaScript is stored in a data dictionary**, and you're just retrieving the functions from that dictionary using their key, which is their name as a string. It's the same as saying `100.toString`, without using parentheses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is bracket notation. Any property can be accessed using either dot- or bracket notation. So since `toString` is a property, you can access it using bracket notation.

For number you can however also use dot-syntax, but you have to make clear to parser that the dot is not a decimal point. For example with *two dots*:

```
100..toString() // equivalent to 100.0.toString
```

To avoid this confusing syntax for numbers, bracket version is preferred. But in most cases dot-notation allows more concise and cleaner syntax, although you can always use brackets when you can use dot.

The benefit of the bracket-syntax is that:

- it should be used to access properties with the name stored in variable
- it allows to access properties with the names that are not valid identifiers.

And the answer to the second question.

> why does 100['toString']['length'] not evaluate to three?

Because `100['toString']` is a method inherited from the `Number.prototype`. Hence this is a function. And the length property of the function is the number of explicit arguments it accepts. [`Number.prototype.toString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.2) takes a radix parameter, the only one. So the result is `1`.

Comment: What is to `toString` a property of. Just, like, a native property of any JS object? Also, in your example why does need two `dots`. Finally, why does `100['toString']['length']` not evaluate to three?

Comment: Why does doing something like this give me `undefined`? `var a = 100.354['parseInt']`

Comment: There is no such property at all. `parseInt` is a global function, or (global object property if you want).

Comment: toString is indeed a property of Object (applies to all objects) (`Object.prototype.toString`)

Comment: @thomas You should use `100['toString']()['length']`, and the reason the double-dot notation works is because the second dot cannot be interpreted as part of a number and therefore assumes you are accessing a property or method.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in JS is an object with potential properties. Accessing a method can be done the same as using the key name in the object. Square brackets can be used on numbers where decimal points cannot as they would be interpreted as part of the number. That's just using the alternative option of calling the Object property `toString` on a Number object.

Comment: `(100).toString` should be equivalent

Comment: `(100).toString` is most readable notation. It's also possible to use space by the way, but this is really weird `100 .toString`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not calling any function at all. It's just accessing the properties using bracket notation.

Dot notation doesn't work for integers, because the compiler apparently doesn't want to test if it's a float or identifier. So, `100.toString` is a syntax error.

Comment: What are some other methods are available? Doing `var a = 100.354['parseInt']` just gets me `undefined`. How could I use it? Pass it a radix? Thanks.

Comment: `parseInt` is global, not a property of the number. Use `parseInt(100.354)`.