# jQuery selector for same classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have several divs inside a `OffersContainer` div. On Page load I show only the First div of `OffersContainer`. Then upon clicking the 'show more', I show first three divs and finally on clicking 'show more' for the second time I show all the divs.

Problem is I have two `OffersContainer` at a time. And I want these two `OffersContainer` div independent of each other. What actually happens is, when for the first time I click on left `OffersContainer's` show more it behaves perfectly i.e show 3 divs. But now when I click show more of right side OffersContainer's div it will show all instead of showing first 3 divs. It means its not working independently of the other div? How can I make it run separately?

P.S: For some reason both of these divs will have same class `OffersContainer` so I can't change the name. What am I doing wrong? Am I using wrong selectors?

[**Here is the Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qo55rmuy/1/)

[**And Here is the Fiddle with just one OffersContainer div just in case anyone wants to see**](https://jsfiddle.net/qo55rmuy/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't store click information in shared global varibale. Instead you can persist it in the class name for each span:

```
$(".OffersContainer > div:gt(0)").hide();

$(".OffersContainer > span").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings($(this).hasClass('click') ? "div:gt(0)" : "div:lt(3)").slideDown();
    $(this).addClass('click');
});
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/qo55rmuy/2/

Comment: So the global variable was mixing things up! Thanks man for pointing it out! Your solution works!

Comment: I have encountered one more problem. On clicking the span for the third time I want it to hide all except first. I tried achieving this behavior but I guess there is the global variable issue again. can you help figure out?
https://jsfiddle.net/qo55rmuy/4/

Comment: This one is a bit tricky. I would not use classes for this, instead keep a click counter for every span: https://jsfiddle.net/qo55rmuy/5/

Comment: Could you explain this line?   `$(this).siblings(this.clickCount % 3 === 1 ? "div:lt(3)" : "div:gt(0)")[command]();`
What is this `[command]` doing?

Comment: `[command]` is the way to call method by variable name. Take a look at details explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27217035/strange-use-of-square-braces-to-call-functions/27217097#27217097

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to hide the relevant `div` elements on initial load. This will solve the issue of the contents of the other `.OfferContainer` elements being completely hidden.

```
.OffersContainer > div:nth-child(n+2) {
    display: none;
}
```

From there you can change the logic so that it is keyed on the number of visible elements, instead of the `click` variable, like this:

```
$(".OffersContainer > span").click(function() {
    var $siblings = $(this).siblings();
    var visibleLength = $siblings.filter(':visible').length;
    $siblings.filter(visibleLength != 1 ? "div:gt(0)" : "div:lt(3)").slideDown();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/qo55rmuy/3/)

Answer (score 1):

That's because when you click the "show more" of the right side the var click is true. You can store the click attribute in [jQuery.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

```
$(".OffersContainer > span").click(function(){
    var click = $.data(this, "click") || false;
    $(this).siblings(click ? "div:gt(0)" : "div:lt(3)").slideDown(); 
    $.data(this, "click", true);
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gykqkxuq/)